# Report Viewer not working because of Report Viewer Configuration Error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Anyone here that can help me about my problem using Report Viewer server control on my ASP MVC application. The issue is web.config settings for Report Viewer always give me an error even though I already set the config for Report Viewer. But when I tried to create a new Web Application for testing Report Viewer works fine.

Here is the Error:

```
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered
in the application's web.config file. Add <add verb="*"
path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type =
"Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.web/httpHandlers
section of the web.config file, or add <add
name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"
verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" /> to the system.webServer/handlers
section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
```

I already did what other solutions in the internet regarding this issue but I still got the same error over and over again.

And upon looking the Developer Tool I found out that **Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd** returning 404 (Not Found) even though I have this in my web.config and I think this causes the error in report viewer.

Here is my web.config:

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
<assemblies>
   <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
   <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" /> 
</assemblies>
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</buildProviders>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
       <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

and here is my code in aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewer.aspx.cs" Inherits="HSESA.Web.Reports.ReportViewer" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="RVForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="RVScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="reportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
               <LocalReport  ReportPath="Reports\AssessmentByRegionReport.rdlc">
               </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help. ^_^

Comment: Have you putting `ReportViewer` load routines in `Page_Load` method? Seems that you need to check postback state using `IsPostBack` property.

Comment: Yes I have that in my Page_Load. I have my Datasource for the Report Viewer but still got the same error. :(

Comment: Can you show code inside `Page_Load` method? As I thought, you need `IsPostBack` check to differentiate first time call with GET and subsequent POST requests.

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    System.Data.DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
                    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/AssessmentByRegionReport.rdlc");
                    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("AssessmentByRegionDataSet", ds.Tables[0]);
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto sorry I don't know how will I comment the code same as I did in my question that's why it ended like that a messy code.

Answer (score 2):

I already know how to solve my own issue. I just put the config for Report Viewer on top of other configuration inside `<handler>` in `<system.webServer>` in Web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  **<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>**
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="WebResourceHandler" path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" />
  <!--<add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
  <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="GifFiles" path="*.gif" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="jpg" path="*.jpg" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="png" path="*.png" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="js" path="*.js" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="css" path="*.css" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="ico" path="*.ico" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="reg" path="*.reg" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <add name="aspx" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
  <add name="star" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It was place at the end of the last item in `<handler>` since it was automatically put there upon saving/build the application. But still I don't know the definite reason why it causes the error when it is in the end of the `<handler>` but my guess somehow is that it is not reachable by the web.config? correct me if I'm wrong if other people know the reason so I could know too. but then it fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing all parameters in Report Data Tab which is not used in the Report.

and web.config is:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
     <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
```